# Twig / Assetic block inheritance - unable to add to initial block with parent()

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I am developing a symfony2 project which incorporates a theming system. Due to the restrictions of this system, I am having to define the javascripts and stylesheets blocks in an include file, which is then included in the theme's layout twig file. The structure is as follows:

app/Resources/themes/{theme_name}/views/layout.html.twig

```
... code ...
{% include '::theme_assets.html.twig; %}
```

app/Resources/views/theme_assets.html.twig

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 
        'stylesheet.css'
        'stylesheet2.css'
        filter='cssrewrite'
        output='css/packed/layout_theme.css'
    %}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts%}
    {# same as stylesheets #}
{% endblock %}
```

I then want to be able to include additional css/js files within the initial blocks set above on individual pages, e.g.

src/Blah/BlahBundle/Resources/views/subpage.html.twig

```
{% extends 'BlahBundle::layout.html.twig' %} {# the theme system works out that there is a theme overrde for this file #}

{% block body %}
    ...body...
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }} {# should include the initial block #}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/bundles/blah/css/additional1.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/bundles/blah/css/additional2.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

For some reason these additional stylesheets aren't included when I view "subpage.html.twig". I highly suspect that the problem lies in my implementation, but I am unsure as to what I can try!

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue but what i've done and working is such as:
I use `layout.html.twig` as base for all my pages. (everything includes this layout). An it has:
`{% block stylesheets %}...
{% endblock %}` and NO `{% stylesheets ... {% endstylesheets %}` additionally in it.
When i want to add a new stylesheet for a single page i call the stylesheet block again like you did, by calling parent, Sf2 adds the css to the end.
But one thing i know with this solution is asset dumping will not allowed as i guess.